# OMedit - Modelling a body with four wheels

Tags: openmodelica

I can't build modells with two rolling wheels. The fun thing about it is, that i can build the model with one wheel. If I add any other wheel anywhere, then it's not working anymore.

I want to build a body with four wheels on it, so i can animate the driving. It works "fine" with one wheel or one wheelset at the body.

```
model Rohmodell
  inner Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.World world(defaultAxisLength = 1, n = {0, 0, -1})  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-90, -90}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.RollingWheelSet wheelSet1(wheelDistance = 2, wheelMass = 31, wheelRadius = 1, wheel_I_axis = 1, wheel_I_long = 1, x(start = 0), y(start = 0)) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, 38}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.Body body1(m = 1000)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {10, 8}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.FixedTranslation fixedTranslation1(r = {-3, 0, 0})  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, -14}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.Body body2(m = 1000) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {10, -38}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.RollingWheelSet wheelSet(wheelDistance = 2, wheelMass = 31, wheelRadius = 1, x(start = -3))  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, -66}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  connect(body1.frame_a, wheelSet1.frameMiddle) annotation(
    Line(points = {{0, 8}, {0, 36}}, color = {95, 95, 95}));
  connect(fixedTranslation1.frame_a, body1.frame_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{0, -4}, {0, 8}}, color = {95, 95, 95}));
  connect(fixedTranslation1.frame_b, body2.frame_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{0, -24}, {0, -38}}, color = {95, 95, 95}));
  connect(wheelSet.frameMiddle, body2.frame_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{0, -68}, {0, -68}, {0, -38}, {0, -38}}, color = {95, 95, 95}));
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.3")));end Rohmodell;
```

The error is very long, so i only post the headers:

Model is structurally singular, error found sorting equations

Internal error Transformation Module PFPlusExt index Reduction Method Pantelides failed!

[Picture of the Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgp3u.png)